# JSON request ignoring '\' during name validation check

Tags: c++, json, postman

While sending the JSON POST request:

```
{
    "name":"\c.3"
}
```

I get a response that completely ignores the '\'. Is this have something to do with how JSON handles that character?

```
{
    "name": "c.3",
    "registered": false
}
```

Comment: "\\a.1" returns value "\a.1"

Comment: is `\a` even a valid escape sequence?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  Are you saying that the return value is actually `\\a.1` and your parser is changing it to `\a.1` or vice-versa? \ is an escape character to denote that the slash is intended.  It sounds like the parsing is escaping the slash for you into one if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, logic will force any characters other than a-z to return an error. This is the only condition that does not validate.

Comment: Judging from the website https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes, `\a` is equivilent to `a`.  Not sure if that website has accurate information, however.  If so, looks like things are behaving as expected.

Comment: Is there any way for the system to capture that \?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is the escape character in JSON, so basically the string sent in the form `"\a.1"` is exactly the same as `"a.1"`. If the former is intended, `"\\a.1"` is the actual string that represents `\a.1`.